# Acceso prohibido! Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al objeto > solicitado.¿ Cómo corregirlo?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, .htaccess, login, session

Tengo el siguiente error, recientemente estoy empezando a trabajar con sesiones de php, cuando añadí la sesión me dice que no tengo permisos para leer la página objetivo, ya agregué un htaccess para quitar las extenciones y añadí un servidor virtual pero sigue sin funcionar, Creen que tenga que ver con el código php?

> ¡Acceso prohibido! Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al objeto
>   solicitado. El objeto está protegido contra lectura o el servidor no
>   puede leerlo.
>
> Si usted cree que esto es un error del servidor, por favor
>   comuníqueselo al administrador del portal.
>
> Error 403 seth.com Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.5

Este es el código que crea el link

```
<?php
     require './conectar.php';

    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $verify = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1');
    $verify->execute(array(':email' => $email));
    $result = $verify->fetch();

    }  if ($result == false) {
      //Generate Vkey
      $vkey = md5(time().$email);

      $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, vkey) VALUES (:email, '$vkey')";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
      $stmt->execute();

      //send mail
      $to = $email;
      $subject = "Correo de verificación";
      $message = "<a href='http://seth.com/plugins/inicio%20de%20sesi%C3%B3n/php/verifykey?vkey=$vkey'>Verificar Cuenta </a>";
      $headers = "From: eduard.rga0@gmail.com \r\n"; 
      $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 " . "\r\n"; 
      $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 
      mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

      header('Location: ./confirmarcorreo');

    } else {
      header('Location: ./nosconocemos');
    }
?>
```

Este es el código que estoy utilizando para redirigir al dashboard:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['vkey'])) {
    //Process Verification
    $vkey = $_GET['vkey'];

    require './conectar.php';

    $resultset = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE verified = 0 AND vkey = :vkey LIMIT 1");
    $resultset->execute(array(':vkey' => $vkey));
    $resultkey = $resultset->fetch();

    if($resultkey !== false) {

        //Validate the email
        $update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET verified = 1 WHERE vkey = '$vkey' LIMIT 1");
        $update->execute();

        $records = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, FROM users WHERE vkey = '$vkey'  LIMIT 1");
        $records->execute();
        $matchbd = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['id'] = $matchbd['id'];
        header('Location: ..../dashboard');

    }else {
        echo "Esta cuenta es invalida";
    }

}else{
    die("Algo salió mal");
}

?>
```

Comment: este error pasa porque mando un email de confirmación, y no me deja acceder desde un link externo, qué puedo hacer en ese caso?

Comment: Estas intentado acceder desde una ip o desde localhost?

Comment: @Riven desde un local Host/Virutal host configurado con Xamp, agregué mis documentos de php

Comment: estas usando 4 puntos para acceder a dashboard.

Comment: @Riven sí, de esa manera encuentra el documento con link relativo, si lo dejo con 2 no accede.

Comment: @Riven se solucionó con un link absoluto, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se solucionó cambiando el link por uno absoluto que llamara al url sin ser objeto.

Comment: Hola, me alegra que encontraras una solución a tu problema. Deberías incluir algo más de información en tu respuesta: ¿qué enlace cambiaste a absoluto? ¿a qué te refieres con lo de "sin ser objeto"? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.